# Using a struct variable as a formal parameter

Tags: c++, function, struct, parameters, declaration

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void input(partsType inventory[100]&)
{}

int main()
{
   struct partsType
   {

      string partName;
      int partNum;
      double price;
      int quantitiesInStock;
   };
   partsType inventory[100];
}
```

I am trying to use a struct variable as a formal parameter. Later I will pass the variable by reference.

Currently, I am getting the error

```
declaration is incompatible, and `partsType` is undefined.
```

Comment: Define `partsType` before `input`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues:

- You need to define the `partsType` outside the `main`, and of-course
  before the `input` function otherwise, it does not know what is `partsType`.
- Secondly, your function parameter syntax is wrong. It should have
  been

  ```
  void input(partsType (&inventory)[100])
  //                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  --> if you meant to pass the array by ref
  ```

So you need:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>   // missing header

struct partsType
{
   std::string partName;
   int partNum;
   double price;
   int quantitiesInStock;
};

void input(partsType (&inventory)[100]) 
{}

int main()
{
   partsType inventory[100];
}
```

---

Another option is to forward declare the struct `partsType` before the `input` function. But, that will need to make the function definition after the main, as you define the struct inside the `main`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>   // missing header

// forward declaration
struct partsType;
void input(partsType(&inventory)[100]);

int main()
{
   struct partsType
   {
      std::string partName;
      int partNum;
      double price;
      int quantitiesInStock;
   };
   partsType inventory[100];
}
void input(partsType(&inventory)[100])
{
   // define
}
```

---

Also do not practice with [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)